# Property 'ReportSource' is 'ReadOnly'

Tags: mysql, vb.net, crystal-reports, report, readonly

I'm currently making a report in VB.net and I've got this Error:

```
    Property 'ReportSource' is 'ReadOnly'.
```

and this is my code:

```
   Imports CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine
```

Imports CrystalDecisions.Shared

Public Class MRTable

```
Private Sub ToolStripButton1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ToolStripButton1.Click
    Dim cryRpt As New ReportDocument

    cryRpt.Load("D:\Orly\workspace\HMIS\01.26.15\HoMISv2.0\CRMedicalRecords.rpt")

    Dim crParameterFieldDefinitions As ParameterFieldDefinitions
    Dim crParameterFieldDefinition As ParameterFieldDefinition
    Dim crParameterValues As New ParameterValues
    Dim crParameterDiscreteValue As New ParameterDiscreteValue

    crParameterDiscreteValue.Value = Nurse.SelectedPatient
    crParameterFieldDefinitions = cryRpt.DataDefinition.ParameterFields
    crParameterFieldDefinition = crParameterFieldDefinitions.Item("PCode")
    crParameterValues = crParameterFieldDefinition.CurrentValues

    crParameterValues.Clear()
    crParameterValues.Add(crParameterDiscreteValue)
    crParameterFieldDefinition.ApplyCurrentValues(crParameterValues)

    CRMedicalRecords.ReportSource = cryRpt
End Sub
```

End Class

I hope that you could help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Please open the report in Crystal Reports, or Visual Studio and check under
File > Report Options
The option Read-Only to be turned off.

Probably this is preventing you from editing the report, as you are doing with adding the parameter.

Comment: thanks for your solution but I solved it.. CRMedicalRecords.ReportSource = cryRpt should be MedicalRecordsReport.CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = cryRpt

Comment: Welcome, overlooked your problem. Great you fixed the problem